# using android static fragment other fragment gets destroyed

Tags: android, static, fragment, android-support-library

The below code behaves differently if support lib Fragment is used or native fragment (not compatibility lib) is used.
Using support lib, the below code destroys BFragment.
Using native fragments, the NFragment will be destroyed.

Does anyone knows why is this difference?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    class BFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy, container, false);
             ((TextView) inflated.findViewById(R.id.txt_dummy)).setText("BFragment");
            return inflated;
        }

    }

    class NFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy, container, false);
             ((TextView) inflated.findViewById(R.id.txt_dummy)).setText("NFragment");
            return inflated;
        }

    }

    static NFragment nfragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nfragment = new NFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new BFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.notification_container, nfragment).commit();

        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new BFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.notification_container, nfragment).commit();

        return true;

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/notification_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       />


    <FrameLayout 
       android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the dummy.xml (used by the fragments):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_dummy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```